# React native app stuck on splash screen on device

Tags: react-native, screen, splash-screen

I read this article (React native app stuck on splash screen on device but works in simulator)
I try to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, and switching the Run step to Release.But it doesn't work for me.
The project has added main.jsbundle file.I also clean build folder, But app still stuck on splash screen on device.
How to fixed?Thanks.

I hope the app can run normally on the device